# Multiple headers while I just want to have a single header

Tags: python, pandas, google-api

So I have this chunk script

```
def alltime_tracker(sheet_url,sheet_name,concatfile):

   temp2 = pd.read_csv(sheet_url)

   temp2 = temp2[(temp2['Time Complete'] != today)]

   temp2 = pd.concat([temp2,concatfile])

   temp2.to_csv(sheet_name,encoding='utf-8', index=False)

sheet1_url = 'https://docs.google.com...' 

sheet1_name = 'sheet1.csv' 

alltime_tracker(sheet1_url,sheet1_name,damagedclaim)
```

This intended output is that the tracker will be updated everyday. The sheet1_url is a blank spreadsheet with headers. While, concatfile is a different spreadsheet filled with headers and data from today. I've connected this script to google gdocs/google API so it automates/run the code everyday. However, when the script runs on the second day, it produced multiple headers (three headers in total and the script has been running for two days). Can anybody help me with this issue so that it only produces 1 header whenever the script runs?. Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't totally clear, but are you sure you're concatenating on the right axes? By default `axes=0` (rows), which shouldn't add headers, but maybe if you explained more it would be clearer.

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for the response. The data itself is confidential. The only thing that I can say is that I'm trying to concatenate the data not from today and the data from today. It keeps going on and on. I just checked the output this morning, yesterday I deleted the 'extra' header, so it came up with only two headers. How do I default the axes?

Comment: Your last question makes me worry...default values mean that they are set without you doing anything. If your data is confidential, you can replace the values with fake numbers, or just give a schema of how things look, what you're trying to do, and what you've done so far.